# 'type' object is not subscriptable python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

here are the functions I defined when I try to call them I get the error
note that resultmatrix is a 4x4 2d numpy array

**
the function is :

```
import numpy as np



def getValues(row,column,resultMatrix):
  a=resultMatrix[row][column]
  prefix='0x'
  a=prefix+a
  an_integer = int(a, 16)
  return an_integer


mixMatrix=np.array([['00','00','00','00'],
                   ['00','00','00','00'],
                   ['00','00','00','00'],
                   ['00','00','00','00']])



def mixColumns(a, b, c, d,column):
  v1=(gmul(a, 2) ^ gmul(b, 3) ^ gmul(c, 1) ^ gmul(d, 1))
  v2=(gmul(a, 1) ^ gmul(b, 2) ^ gmul(c, 3) ^ gmul(d, 1))
  v3=(gmul(a, 1) ^ gmul(b, 1) ^ gmul(c, 2) ^ gmul(d, 3))
  v4=(gmul(a, 3) ^ gmul(b, 1) ^ gmul(c, 1) ^ gmul(d, 2))
  v1=hex(v1); char0=v1[2];char1=v1[3];v1=str(char0+char1)
  mixMatrix[0][column]=v1
  v2=hex(v2); char0=v2[2];char1=v2[3];v2=str(char0+char1)
  mixMatrix[1][column]=v2
  v3=hex(v3); char0=v3[2];char1=v3[3];v3=str(char0+char1)
  mixMatrix[2][column]=v3
  v4=hex(v4); char0=v4[2];char1=v4[3];v4=str(char0+char1)
  mixMatrix[3][column]=v4
  return mixMatrix

  def gmul(a, b):
   if b == 1:
    return a
   tmp = (a << 1) & 0xff
   if b == 2:
    return tmp if a < 128 else tmp ^ 0x1b
   if b == 3:
    return gmul(a, 2) ^ a
```

- when I call as shown bellow I receive the error

  ```
     a=getValues(0,0,resultMatrix);b=getValues(1,0,resultMatrix);c=getValues(2,0,resultMatrix);d=getValues(3,0,resultMatrix);mixColumns(a, b, c, d,0)
  ```

[image: a screen shot of the error message]

Comment: Please format the question correctly and give enough information for someone to search an answer. How are we expected to solve the issue if we don't even know what `mixColumns` and `getValues` does.

Comment: sorry it was my first time using stack overflow,  appreciated

Comment: show the full error message

Comment: @hpaulj I posted it, thank you

Comment: What's this `resultMatrix` that you pass to `getValues`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be from the `mixColumns` function you cast the `v1`, `v2`, `v3` and `v4` to hexadecimal then you extract the third and fourth character.
However you can't get the fourth character when the value is below 15 since the
hex value will be on only 3 character (0 => 0x0, 15 => 0xF, 16 => 0x10).

If the idea is to get the hexadecimal value without the "0x" in front of it then you can simply use `v1 = v1[2:]` which mean take everything from the third character.

If the goal is to take the first two hexadecimal character and ignoring the rest, then you need to check if there is enough character:

```
char0 = v1[2]
char1 = v1[3] if len(v1) >= 4 else "0"
```

So after correcting this, you'll have a `mixColumns` function that look like

```
def mixColumns(a, b, c, d,column):
  v1=(gmul(a, 2) ^ gmul(b, 3) ^ gmul(c, 1) ^ gmul(d, 1))
  v2=(gmul(a, 1) ^ gmul(b, 2) ^ gmul(c, 3) ^ gmul(d, 1))
  v3=(gmul(a, 1) ^ gmul(b, 1) ^ gmul(c, 2) ^ gmul(d, 3))
  v4=(gmul(a, 3) ^ gmul(b, 1) ^ gmul(c, 1) ^ gmul(d, 2))
  
  v1=hex(v1)
  v1=v1[2:]
  mixMatrix[0][column]=v1

  v2=hex(v2)
  v2=v2[2:]
  mixMatrix[1][column]=v2

  v3=hex(v3)[2:] #Same thing but shorter
  mixMatrix[2][column]=v3

  v4=hex(v4)[2:]
  mixMatrix[3][column]=v4
  return mixMatrix
```

Comment: thank you for the useful explanation but after applying your solution unfortunately it throws the same error